# Erlang - serialize a string (with no newlines/carriage returns)?

Tags: serialization, erlang, erl

I've seen some answers to this in other programming languages, but not a specific erlang one. I'm able to read the file and I use:

```
re:replace(Subject, RE, Replacement, Options)
```

specifically:

```
re:replace(Content, "\r" , " ",[global,{return,list}]),
```

to remove those escape sequences (I believe that's what they are called)

And it perfectly replaces all the \r with a space. So my question is:

1) is there a way to put multiple replacements in RE, so I could also remove "\n"?
2) is there a different/better/more efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the basics of regular expressions.

In your first question, you can use the solution:

```
re:replace(Content, "[\r\n]", " ", [global, {return, list}])
```

Erlang string syntax is not convenient enough, if you need to do a lot of very complex string processing, you should consider using another language.

Comment: **re:replace/4** uses **re:do_replace/5** which uses **re:run/3**. According to the [Code](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/stdlib/src/re.erl#L96) **re:run/3** is native code and is so fast.

Comment: Where you got erlang has very poor string processing performance? Which language you thing has better. If you thing about Perl then I can tell you are wrong. As somebody who wrote hundreds of thousand lines of Perl professionally, you can write some text processing more elegantly in Perl and some in Erlang but well-written Erlang will be usually more efficient.

Comment: @Hynek -Pichi- Vychodil Thanks for your comment, you're right, the answer is changed.